# Amazon S3 S3DirectoryInfo LastWriteTimeUtc is very slow

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm iterating over an Amazon S3 bucket which contains only 1 folder. 
I'm using C# and this code to get the contents:

```
s3Root.GetDirectories();
```

It works fast, then I assign the results to a custom object like this

```
foreach (var subdirectories in s3Root.GetDirectories())
{
    var item = subdirectories.FullName.Split(':')[1].Replace('\\', '/').TrimStart('/');
    var itemUrl = FullBucketUrl + item;
    myList.Add(new S3Info(subdirectories, itemUrl, "Folder", item));
}
```

Then in the constructor of S3Info I have this variable assignment

```
LastModified = itemInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc;
```

Where itemInfo is S3DirectoryInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc

The complete call takes about 13 seconds, and that last assigment takes more than 11 seconds. Why?

Does that call go to S3 again? I don't get it, and even going even to S3 why 11 seconds!?

s3Root.GetDirectories() is returning S3DirectoryInfo[] not a deferred one like IQueryable or IEnumerable, so it should be already materialized from what I see.

Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, accessing that property (as well as most other properties on that class) is going to S3. `S3DirectoryInfo` and related classes are intended to mimic the `System.IO.*Info` classes, which don't actually cache any information. `GetDirectories` is just pulling a list of object keys from S3.

The last write date isn't actually stored on the object representing the folder, either. It's calculated by enumerating every object in the folder and returning the latest, which can be incredibly slow for large folders.

If you want to optimize this and reduce the number of round trips, your best bet is to use `AmazonS3Client.ListObjects` to grab large batches of objects and figure out the last write date for each folder manually.